# Scanner.reset() doesn't work

Tags: java

This piece of code is supposed to get an integer number from user and then finish the program. If the user inputs an invalid number, it asks user again.

After catching exception, it uses `Scanner.reset()` to reset the scanner, but it doesn't work. and it re-throws previous exception.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
        long i = in.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Thanks, you entered: ");
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in your input");
        in.reset(); // <----------------------------- [The reset is here]
    }
}
```

I thought `Scanner.reset()` will reset everything and forget the exception. I put it before asking the user for a new input.

If I get the point wrong, what is the right way?

Comment: What do you think `Scanner.reset()` does? Read the API documentation for that method.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `reset()` ? Are you attempting to ask for user input again ? That is not what `reset()` does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You misunderstood the purpose of the `reset` method: it is there to reset the "metadata" associated with the scanner - its whitespace, delimiter characters, and so on. It does not change the state of its input, so it would not achieve what you are looking for.

What you need is a call of `next()`, which reads and discards any `String` from the `Scanner`:

```
try {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
    long i = in.nextLong();
    System.out.print("Thanks, you entered: ");
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error in your input");
    in.next(); // Read and discard whatever string the user has entered
}
```

Relying upon exceptions to catch exceptional situations is OK, but an even better approach to the same issue would be using `has...` methods before calling the `next...` methods, like this:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
if (!in.hasNextLong()) {
    in.next();
    continue;
}
long i = in.nextLong();
System.out.print("Thanks, you entered: ");
System.out.println(i);
break;
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [Scanner.reset() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset%28%29), the method only "resets" locale, radix and delimiter settings. It does not do anything to the data it already read.