# How to I manage a user entering a letter instead of number?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to write a Vending Machine program and have it pretty well done aside from telling it how to handle a user typing a letter in instead of a number. This is the chunk of code I'm trying to figure out:

```
System.out.print("Please enter how much money you have to spend (enter -1 to shut down): ");
        double custMoney = scanner.nextDouble();
        if (custMoney <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for your business!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

If a user types in a letter instead of a number though, it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at VendingMachine1.main(VendingMachine1.java:28)
```

How can I resolve this so that if they enter a letter it will prompt them to enter a valid number?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would write the code for that though

Comment: Google it and you will know. "How to read in a String", "How to convert a String to a number".

Comment: Actually with `scanner.hasNextDouble` you can check whether the input is a double or not and can act accordingly without having to catch any exception (you shouldn't call `nextDouble` if it's not a double :) BTW: This is surprisingly close to another question where I've just posted a minimal examples with integer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28664940/1063730

Answer (score 1):

As @Max said, you should read the input as a String and alert the user when it isn't a number, I've added the while(!numberOk) so that if a user enters a letter in stead of a number (or an invalid number) it would keep asking ;)

Hopefully this helps you

```
   String custMoney = scanner.next();
    double custMoneyValue;
    boolean numberOk=false;
    while(!numberOk)
    try {
        custMoneyValue = Double.parseDouble(custMoney);
        if (custMoneyValue <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for your business!");
            numberOk=true;
            System.exit(0); // would make the while loop condition useless...

        }
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please insert a number...");
            custMoney = scanner.next();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to people directly here and format it correctly... But I posted a comment on my post if you could look at it and tell me what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code example for double

```
try {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
    long i = in.nextLong();
    System.out.print("Thanks, you entered: ");
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
}
 catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error in your input");
    in.next(); // Read and discard whatever string the user has entered
}
```