# While loop with try-catch blocks doesn't wait for input in the try block after looping once

Tags: java, validation, input, exception

So I've got a method getInput, that is meant to, well, ask user for input, use a try-catch to make sure it's a correct data type(int in this case) and validate whether it's in a predefined range. Problem is, when I enter, say, a string, it repeats the message about incorrect input, prints the message I have asking for input in try {} and goes straight to catch without waiting for input.
Here's the code:

```
public static int getInput(String message, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    while (true) {
        int input;
        try {
            System.out.println(message);
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            if (lowerLimit > input && input > upperLimit) {
                return input;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input value, try again");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input, try again");
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are other, working ways of accomplishing this, but I'd like to know why this one doesn't work - I think it should. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the definition of `scanner`?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15973109/1291717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're observing stems from the fact that scanner (assuming you're working with `java.util.Scanner`) only advances if `nextInt()` is successful. That means that you have to skip over the faulty input (i.e. by using `next()`) before proceding.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (lowerLimit > input && input > upperLimit)
```

This is ALWAYS `false`.  You meant

```
if (input >= lowerlimit && input <= upperLimit)
    return input;
```

Comment: Nit: not always. What if `lowerLimit > upperLimit`? I mean, that'd be logically incorrect, but that's not explicitly prevented...

Comment: Thanks, you are right - it wasn't the cause of the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Scanner` class, you could check, whether token has `int` or not

```
 if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
  int input = scanner.nextInt();
     if (lowerLimit > input && input < upperLimit) {
     return input;
      } 
   }
  else 
   {
      System.out.println("Incorrect input value, try again");
    }
```